# Name server not working

Tags: dns, webserver, nameservers

I got a new server from 10gbps.io and setup the dns/hostname accordingly but when I check my domain federalwardogs.com with whatsmydns.net I get errors and some users cant access the site or see the site.

I'm currently using ns3.tbuilds.org and ns4.tbuilds.org but I still can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

[image]

It's been over 5 days and still nothing :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think http://www.serverfault.com is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: I spent some time looking into this, and it really is strange.

Comment: Still, [whois](http://whois.domaintools.com/federalwardogs.com) states that domain records were updated today, so maybe it used to be misconfigured but was corrected in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding an A record in my domain @ and the servers IP address